# If A and B are compact sets, then A ∩ B is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If A and B are compact sets, then A ∩ B is compact.

my approach is since A and B are compact, for every open covers of A and B, there exists finite sub-covers to cover A and B. Since A ∩ B is a subset of A, for each finite sub-cover of A, there is a sub-cover of that sub-cover to cover A ∩ B. Therefore, A ∩ B is compact. Is my proof rigorous enough?

Comment: Doesn't look convincing to me. When you want to prove that $A\cap B$ is compact, you need to start with some _arbitrary_ open cover of $A\cap B$. This needs not be a cover of $A$ nor of $B$. What do you do then?

Comment: No, your proof is not correct. Note that what you are saying is that any subset of a compact set is compact, what is not true.

Comment: Do you know that your $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R^n$? If you know the compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are exactly the closed and bounded ones, then a proof from this characterization will be is almost immediate. On, the other hand, if $A$ and $B$ live in an arbitrary topological space (perhaps not even Hausdorff so you're not guaranteed that $A$ and $B$ are _closed_), then your claim is not necessarily true. What exactly are your assumptions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assume that the space is Hausdorff so that compact sets ar closed. $A\subset \cup_i V_i$ ($V_i$'s open ) implies $A \subset B^{c} \cap \cup_i V_i$ and this gives an open cover for $A$. Let $A \subset B^{c} \cap \cup_{k=1}^{N} V_{i_k}$. Then $A \cap B$ is covered by $V_{i_k}$,$1\leq k\leq N$.